# Object is not Iterable - for line in lines: -- lane detection in opencv

Tags: python

I am trying to write a lane detection script using OpenCv-python

for my average_slope_intercept function I have the code:

```
def avg_slope_int(frame, lines):
    left_fit = []
    right_fit = []
    for line in lines:
        x1, y1, x2, y2 = line.reshape(4)
        # fitting the polynomial, intercept and slope
        # fitting the polynomial, intercept and slope
        param = np.polyfit((x1, x2), (y1, y2), 1)
        slope = param[0]
        y_intercept = param[1]
        if slope < 0:
            left_fit.append((slope, y_intercept))
        else:
            right_fit.append((slope, y_intercept))

    left_fit_avg = np.average(left_fit, axis=0)
    right_fit_avg = np.average(right_fit, axis=0)
    left_line = create_cord(frame, left_fit_avg)
    right_line = create_cord(frame, right_fit_avg)
    return np.array([left_line, right_line])
```

when i try to compile it at the end of the script using:

```
while(cap.isOpened()):
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    canny_image = canny_edge(frame)

    cropped_image = region_interest(canny_image)

    linesp = cv2.HoughLinesP(cropped_image, 2, np.pi / 180, 100, np.array([]), minLineLength=40, maxLineGap=5)

    average_lines = avg_slope_int(frame, linesp)

    line_image = display_lines(frame, average_lines)

    cv2.imshow("hough", line_image)

    combo_image = cv2.addWeighted(frame, 0.8, line_image,1,1)

    cv2.imshow('results', combo_image)
    if cv2.waitKey(10) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
```

it returns the error

File "/home/bendevo/PycharmProjects/OpenCV/LaneDetectionAttempts/NewLaneDetection.py", line 88, in 
    average_lines = avg_slope_int(frame, linesp)
  File "/home/bendevo/PycharmProjects/OpenCV/LaneDetectionAttempts/NewLaneDetection.py", line 38, in avg_slope_int
    for line in lines:
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

Comment: Check to see what linesp is by inserting print(linesp) after linesp = cv2.HoughLibesP(). The error message indicates that it is “None”

Comment: I printed it out, I am not sure what it is supposed to return, as it is used as an argument in the next line for "avg_slope_int" function

Comment: I don’t think I’ll be able to help much if you don’t know what it’s supposed to return. When you printed it what was printed?

Comment: @Ethan thank you for replying. I actually figured it out. I converted my x and y points to ints and since one of my functions was returning 0 slopes, i just needed to implement a try and except within the function to only pass non-zero slopes.